# Use the loop to check if DB record exists?

Tags: loop, database, mysql

I have a somewhat unorthodox (i guess) question. I have a function that adds a records to my MYSQL DB, with location lat and lng info. However sometimes that function is not working correctly, causing for the the DB record not to be created. Therefore I would like to create a loop to keep checking if the function created the DB record and if not, do the function again.

I have the following in my functions.php and it seems to be working. I really would like to know if this is a proper way to accomplish the above, since I am not sure. Thanks

```
global $wpdb;
$myccount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."gmw_locations WHERE object_id = %d", $post_id));
    if ($myccount <= 0) :
      while ($myccount <= 0) :
         gmw_pt_update_location( $args ); //The function I would like to check.
         $myccount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."gmw_locations WHERE object_id = %d", $post_id));
      endwhile;
    endif;
```

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea, figure out why it sometimes fails instead

Comment: Hi, it is a script that has been written by the GEO my WordPress plugin that is not working properly: http://docs.geomywp.com/gmw_pt_update_location/#examples

I understand what you say, i guess it has something to do with the google maps api.. Is the above idea as terrible as it looks? thanks:)

Comment: If it didn't work the first time why do you think it would work if you repeat it multiple times? The address or whatever is probably incorrect or incomplete. You shouldn't repeatedly attempt the function, you should log somewhere that the attempt has failed so that you can correct the issue before reattempting.

Comment: I guess it just has something to do with the api response time. As said it uses the standard geomywp script and it is not always working. Especially when using a longer address... I am using the default geomywp locater field with autocomplete function so the address should be complete.